# How to return an object from a list in java

Tags: java

So  i have create  my  Car class  and  now i need to sout the model Ferrari

here  is my code (sout version)

```
for (int b = 0; b < carList.size(); b++) {
        if (carList.get(b).getMark().equalsIgnoreCase("ferrari")) {
            System.out.println("This is Ferrari  : " + carList.get(b));
        }

    }
```

output for this code is :

```
This is Ferrari  : Car{color='Green', price=300000, power=750, mark='Ferrari', model='SP-90', age='2020'}
This is Ferrari  : Car{color='black', price=1305000, power=565, mark='Ferrari', model='Roma', age='2018'}
```

Since my list  have 2 ferarri

Now i am  curios how to use retrun(since i am new in this field) , to  return  the same output i have used  with  the (sout veriosn) above .

Comment: `return carList.get(b).toString();`

Comment: Hint: learning programming is mostly: about trying things yourself. Dont make it your FIRST impulse to ask other people for explanations . You see: any good book or tutorial answers your question. And gives you the necessary context. So, please understand: this isnt programming school here were people **teach** you programming. Meaning: especially for all these basic questions, it is much more helpful for your skills ... to do *research* yourself. Read books, use search engines, etc.

Comment: Understood  @GhostCat

Comment: You are welcome. And note: of course we gladly help with specific questions, but as said: dont make it your first impulse to ask here. When you dig into a topic, and you can't get your code to work, even after hours of trying, then of course: you can come ask here!

Comment: Do you want to return all the objects at the same time?

Comment: @Prog_G
so as i cannot return in void method  , i  need  to create another metod that return my list of cars (only the one with the same model)
so i  have  2  classes     
1 = main  and second is  car 
now i  get confused with the  return , since i  want to retrun  the same  as  sout it's giving to me :( .
i get really  confused zith the return  here . i need to  figure it out at the moment since i cannt get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below function to get all the Ferrari Car object list:

```
List<Car> getFerrariCarList(ArrayList<Car> carList){
        List<Car> newCarList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int b = 0; b < carList.size(); b++) {
            if (carList.get(b).getMark().equalsIgnoreCase("ferrari")) {
                newCarList.add(carList.get(b));
//                System.out.println("This is Ferrari  : " + carList.get(b));
            }
        }
        return newCarList;
    }
```

**Update 1:**

**Main2.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main2 {
    private static Object Car;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car("PodiumBlue", 18500, 165, "Fiat", "Abarth", 2019);
        Car car2 = new Car("Blue", 9500, 105, "Renualt", "Laguna", 2001);
        Car car3 = new Car("Green", 300000, 750, "Ferrari", "SP-90", 2020);
        Car car4 = new Car("Black", 80500, 650, "BMW", "M5-Competition", 2021);
        Car car5 = new Car("black", 1305000, 565, "Ferrari", "Roma", 2018);
        List<Car> carList = Arrays.asList(car1, car2, car3, car4, car5);
        List<Car> ferrariCars = getFerrariCarList(carList);
        System.out.println(ferrariCars);
    }

    static List<Car> getFerrariCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        List<Car> newCarList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int b = 0; b < carList.size(); b++) {
            if (carList.get(b).getMark().equalsIgnoreCase("ferrari")) {
                newCarList.add(carList.get(b));
            }
        }
        return newCarList;
    }
}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private int price;
    private int power;
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private Integer age;

    public Car(String color, int price, int power, String mark, String model, Integer age) {
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.power = power;
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my  post ,  and i  also  have tryed your option but i  get no retrun :(  ( for sure i do something wrong )

Comment: Please add the full class code you are using

Comment: i  added above :)

Comment: Add the Car class

Comment: So  i create  this  
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private int price;
    private int power;
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private Integer age;

Then i  generate constructor   + setter and getter  + to string
I cannot add the code class to since  i  get some error   it's to long

Comment: Thank you .
It is making  more sens for me now  ,  i mean  i understand how return works , since i  was thinking imust use retrun as a  print but  i was getting  null result in the end ,  Thanks again ,   
I  will need to do a recap on this one + build something  again and do it  to  fully understand
Wish you all the best !

Comment: To learn better i  have crete other  tasks that push me to create a return for each one apart  in the same  method :)

Comment: @BecaliNr1 if my answer is correct you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry  , i  am new in this  and i  didn't know i have to  :d
It's accepted